# Document Object Model issues

Tags: javascript

ok, I"m having serious problems with the DOM when I do ANY kind of Javascript. the following snippet of code doesn't work, for some reason that I can't begin to fathom. Whenever I try to use the getElementById() function, the script stops working. please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
var total=0;
document.write("test");
function quickTotal(price,id){
    alert(price)
    alert(id)
    var object=getElementById(id)
    if(object.checked == 1){
        total=parseFloat(total)+parseFloat(price)
        alert("add")
    }
    if(object.checked == 0){
        total=parseFloat(total)-parseFloat(price)
        alert("subtract")
}

    alert(total)
    //document.floater.price.innerHTML("test")
}
```

Comment: no semicolon's in the function

Answer (score 7):

Try using `document.getElementById(id)` (prefix it with `document`, since the method is on the `document` object, not `window`).

*Update: an example with your code:*

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myChkBox" />
<input type="button" onclick="quickTotal(30, 'myChkBox');" value="Click me" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var total = 0;
    document.write("test");
    function quickTotal(price, id) {
        alert(price);
        alert(id);
        var object = document.getElementById(id);
        if (object.checked == 1) {
            total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(price);
            alert("add");
        }
        if (object.checked == 0) {
            total = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(price);
            alert("subtract");
        }

        alert(total);
        //document.floater.price.innerHTML("test")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I changed the reference to document.getElementById(id). and it still doesn't work. Do I need to include a library of some kind for getElementById?

Comment: @DavidBrilliant methods of the document object are native to the browser, you shouldn't have to do anything to get them.

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have an element (a checkbox input) whose id matches what you're looking for? I've updated my answer with your example (code errors fixed and some HTML elements) which works fine.